# How to go to a new scene as a collision event in Lua and Corona SDK?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, collision

Leading on from my last question, I have some obstacles which move across the screen. I need my app to go to the end game screen when my car (called "car") collides with one of the obstacles. Here is my code so far.

```
    function obstacles()
        local function onCollision( event )
            if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
                composer.gotoScene( "end", "fade", 500 )
            end
        end
        local obstacle = display.newLine( display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight - 72, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight - 102 )
        obstacle:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
        obstacle:setStrokeColor( 1, 0, 0, 1 )
        obstacle.strokeWidth = 18
        transition.to( obstacle, { time = 3000, x=-70, onComplete=obstacles } )
    end
```

Whenever I seem to run the script and the car hits the obstacles nothing happens. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your collision event is working, but your gotoScene function is not. You need to check the docs: [gotoScene() function](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/composer/gotoScene.html)

You only need 2 parameters, the first is the name of the scene, the second is an optional table with parameters for the transition.

Try first to execute `composer.gotoScene ("end")`

If it works you can try:

```
local options = {
    effect = "fade",
    time = 500
}
composer.gotoScene( "end", options )
```